# current sessions in Grails

Tags: grails

I am a beginner in Grails 2.0 framework and I am trying to follow this tutorial  http://grails.org/Simple+Avatar+Uploader . I implemented this code but I am getting an error in UserController.groovy at this line  'def user = User.current(session)' as ' No such property: User for class: grailtwitter.PersonController'  I assume that this line takes the user's current session. I am looking for an explanation of how this works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is incomplete. The controller presupposes that you have a way of identifying the currently logged in user. Implicitly the line `def user = User.current(session)` assumes that you have defined a `current()` method on the user class itself that takes in a session and presumably uses some field that you've set in it to retrieve a User. That would be kind of dumb.

A common way to do this would be to build your own authentication mechanism. Note that this is a naive practice and you are **far better off** using [Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) unless you want to leave your application open for *gaping security holes*. But, for practice, something like:

```
def login = {
    //if you're stupid enough to store your passwords in plain text and not sanitize user inputs, you deserve to be hacked
    def user = User.findByPassword(params.password) 
    if(user){
       session.user = user
    }
}
```

You could then replace the offending line in the tutorial (--`def user = User.current(session)`--) with

```
def user = session.user ?: new User(userid:"I'm a little teapot")
```

Before you go much further, you probably want to walk through this [free eBook on Grails](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started) before you get much further. Also highly recommend [Grails in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988932).

Answer (score 0):

When I have run into this in the past it's because I didn't import the class and Grails/Groovy thinks I'm trying to access a variable called User rather than a method on the class.

Comment: what kind of data 'current(session)' hold ?

Comment: What package is the User class in?  If it's not in grailtwitter package then you need to import.

Comment: well.. i imported package. Now i am getting different error as follows "No signature of method: org.grails.twitter.User.current() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsHttpSession) values: [Session Content: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.FLASH_SCOPE = org.codehaus........... "

Comment: I think you overlooked the comment on that line of code that said `// or however you select the current user`.  In other words, you probably can't copy and paste that code and expect it to work.  You need some other way of getting a user.